# Правило для urlManager

Tags: php, yii2

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при url вида /catalog загружалась одна модель, при /catalog?id=1 уже другая модель, а при /catalog?id=1&show=1 эта же модель, но с другой вьюшкой

Контроллер получается такой
`

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $catalogs = CatalogCat::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index', compact('catalogs'));
}
public function actionProduct($id)
{
    $catalogs = Catalog::find()->where(['category_id' => $id])->all();
    return $this->render('product', compact('catalogs'));

}
public function actionShow($id, $show)
{
    $catalogs = Catalog::find()->where(['id' => $show])->one();
    return $this->render('show', compact('catalogs'));
}
```

Такое правило, не загружает другую вьюшку `'catalog?id=<id:\d+>'=>'catalog/product',` только если так загружается другая вьюшка `'catalog/product?id=<id:\d+>'=>'catalog/product',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте так

```
'work/<id:\d+>'=>'work/view',
```

Это при условии, что "work" не является модулем и сработает это правило только для контроллера WorkController.

p.s.
Подождите, если Вам надо получить url в виде /work?id=1, то зачем Вам настраивать UrlManager? Просто отключите его и всё.

p.s.s.
Вам в правилах надо всё равно указывать действия, к каким именно надо обращаться в данном контроллере.Хотя изначально Вы говорили о "work", теперь о "catalog"...

```
'catalog' => 'catalog/index',
'catalog/<_a:[\w\-]+>' => 'catalog/<_a>'
```

Эти правила будут вести на действия index, product, show. Без подобных правил Ваш urlManager не поймёт, в какие действия передавать параметры.
Теперь, если Вы сформируете ссылку в таком формате

```
Html::a('Link name', ['catalog/product', 'id' => 1]);
```

то должны будете попасть в действие "product" и передать туда параметр "id"

```
catalog/product?id=1
```

Для действия "show" ссылка может выглядеть так

```
Html::a('Link name', ['catalog/show', 'id' => 1, 'show' => 2])
```

получить должны в итоге

```
catalog/show?id=1&show=2
```

Ну вот как-то так. Без указания действия в правилах ничего не получится.

Comment: Тогда будет url вида /work/1, а мне надо /work?id=1, так как имеется вывод категорий, в них каталог, а дальше вывод всей информации отдельного каталога, то есть получится большой url если делать к примеру /work/product?id=1/show?num=1, а хотелось бы /work?id=1&show=1

Comment: В таком случае переформулируйте свой вопрос, опишите подробно, что именно Вам надо получить. И отключите вообще urlManager, тогда будут передаваться параметры так, как Вам надо.

Comment: Если я его отключу, то у остальных будет не правильный адрес.

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос.

Comment: для этого не нужно натсроить роутинг. Получайте параметры с url и все

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы при url вида /catalog загружалась одна модель, при /catalog?id=1 уже другая модель, а при /catalog?id=1&show=1 эта же модель, но с другой вьюшкой

Comment: обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, к сожалению не могу поставить +1 из за низкой репутации

Comment: Отметьте решением для других соискателей ответа на похожий вопрос.